# Boot directly into application without showing desktop

Tags: lubuntu, gui, window, window-manager, startup-applications

I am looking to use an old Dell Latitude laptop as a media extender.  I am looking for the laptop to boot directly into the application without showing the dekstop at all. Currently i added the application to the startup list via lubuntu applications, but desktop flashes for good 15 seconds(yes its a slow hdd too) before opening the application. Is it somehow possible to maybe bypass loading the desktop but still be able to run the application?i have tried running it through the command line by booting into text mode but it cant load the GUI as expected. I think in order to achive that i need to load a window manager or similar. Sorry, my knowledge with linux is limited. Thank you.

Comment: What release of Lubuntu?   Are you using LXQt or LXDE?

Comment: LXDE. Based off  Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity, or no desktop (ie. server) are still supported; however Lubuntu & other desktops/flavors on Ubuntu 16.04 are now EOL & thus you should consider upgrade for security reasons (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes).  I would build it on server (and not an EOL desktop) or on a simple wm (window manager) but would start with something that is still supported (ie. 18.04, if 16.04 it'll mean Unity only)

Comment: You haven't given us details as to what program you are running, and why you need a desktop - thus is a simple window manager an option? or why not a server (no desktop).  The key from the provided link is "*Ubuntu 16.04 LTS will be supported for 5 years for Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Core, and Ubuntu Kylin. All other flavours will be supported for 3 years.*" where 16.04 means the 2016-April release of Ubuntu; ie. 3 years are now gone.

Comment: Wasnt aware lubuntu 16.04 was EOL. I never read it because iv been running 16.04 on a diffrent laptop since it was released.Thank you. I just use it because anything 18.04 based takes forever to boot and is slow(tried few distros) Is only a 32 bit pentium M cpu though so limited in choices and power. Building it off server with a wm would most likely be the best i have done that before for a diffrent low spec'd laptop.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS is not EOL.  If you are using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS server, or Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (desktop with default Unity) it's still supported, however flavors such as Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu-MATE, Ubuntu-GNOME, Kubuntu etc. are now EOL as they had only 3 years of supported life.   I have a pentium m (thinkpad t43) which has Lubuntu 18.04 on it  (addition of snapd slowed boot down, but I'm not sure removing that functionality is wise for security reasons) - but I'd suggest something with support of partially-EOL system (eg. 16.04 with other desktop)

Comment: Well yes i meant the flavors.i have 1 lubuntu, and 2 xubuntu systems so they all are at end. Iv just had speed  issues with the 18.04 flavors booting on a c2d and celeron m but it very well could have been a one time thing. And i think i will try a newer server image and window manager and see. Thank you